# "Pongo absolutely-ed heartily."

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "*absolutely-ed*" in [this sentence](http://books.google.com/books?id=HC-OBeh2d3sC&lpg=PA291&ots=-hens56mWR&dq=Pongo%20%22absolutely-ed%22&pg=PA291#v=onepage&q=Pongo%20%22absolutely-ed%22&f=false)?

[image]

Comment: Today, it's a very common, rather "California-ish" idiom.  It's fantastic to see that it was used by Wodehouse in the early 1900s!!  A great question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The author is making use of the ability to make any part of speech into a verb. This is known as *verbing* (or *verbification*), and usually takes place with nouns. In this case, *absolutely* is used as an interjection; when an interjection is verbed, it usually refers to *saying* that interjection. Other examples of verbing:

> Beer me. = Give me a beer.
>
> Ow! You elbowed me! = Ow! You hit me with your elbow!
>
> Friend me. = Add me as a friend. (On Facebook, &c.)

Therefore, *absolutely-ed* (or perhaps more properly, *“absolutely”-ed*) is the past tense of the verbed quotation *“absolutely”*, which means *to say “absolutely”*, and is derived from the interjection/adverb *absolutely*.

It's important to note that it's still *very* uncommon to verb words like *absolutely* or *yes* or *hey*. When quotations such as this are turned into verbs, it's most often in commentary on something a third party has just said:

> Child: Mom! Mom!
>
> Father: Honey, she's “Mom”-ing again.

On a more common note, there are *countless* verbs in English that come from nouns.

[Wikipedia's article on verbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_%28linguistics%29) says:

> Examples of verbification in the English language number in the thousands, including some of the most common words, such as *mail* and *e-mail*, *strike*, *talk*, *salt*, *pepper*, *switch*, *bed*, *sleep*, *ship*, *train*, *stop*, *drink*, *cup*, *lure*, *mutter*, *dress*, *dizzy*, *divorce*, *fool*, *merge*, and many more, to be found on virtually every page in the dictionary.

Comment: @Joe Blow: Yes, that's what I was trying to convey. Edited to clarify.

Comment: I love your edit exampling how you would probably put the word itself in quotes -- quite right!

Comment: Means I can say, this sentence is correct: "Why are you adulating me ?" ?. That should mean - "why are you needlessly admiring me ?". Am I correct ?

Comment: @poorenglish: Well, yes, but *adulate* is already a verb of its own.

Comment: Is "verbing" itself the very example of verbing? I mean the word "verb" is a noun, but after making it into a verb "-ing" is then suffixed to form a gerund "verbing" ...

Comment: @Lukman: You got it.

Answer (score 7):

It means he said the word "Absolutely!" and that he did that with real gusto.

("[Heartily](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/heartily)" means with feeling, loudly, from the heart.)

Comment: This is not standard usage.  The author is presumably putting it this way for comic effect.

Comment: Hmm, it's a common idiom, these days, @mgkr.  You take a word and add "-ed" to make it a verb, meaning the person said that thing.  (Rather similar to how you could use "laughed" or "snorted.")  So, my daughter just humm-ed, my californian friend just Like-d, my aussie cousin just mateyed.